# Auto Increment Surrogate Key in Power Designer

Tags: sql, oracle, datamodel, powerdesigner

I have a Conceptual Data Model in Power Designer, and I need to have a SQL script that add and manage surrogate key on my dimensions tables, but I don't know if it's a good way to do it.

Is there another way to add surrogate key and to increment them automatically ?

I know that I can use Transformations option or Custom Check, but i don't know what is the best solution.

Comment: Why do you manage such details in a Conceptual DM, and not in a Physical Data Model?

Comment: For Oracle, I guess you can create a sequence, and update the surrogate key column with this sequence, in a Before Insert trigger.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my CDM and generated a PDM.
Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finally give an answer, according to Pascals' comment

I've created a sequence :

```
create sequence SK_SEQUENCES
increment by 1
start with 1
  nomaxvalue
  minvalue 1
nocycle
order
keep;
```

and add a trigger to the Surrogate Key

```
create or replace trigger incrsk
before insert on schema.table
for each row
   begin
      :new.SKTEST := SK_SEQUENCES.NEXTVAL;
   end;
/
```

So every time that I add a row to the table, the SK is incremented by 1.